# General Slurm and unix format suggestion

Tags: linux, slurm

I am looking for suggestions to overcome the problem I am facing. To provide context, I am trying to develop a tool for monitoring our in-house HPC clusters. Since we use `slurm` workload scheduling, I have made use of the provided commands from them.

I am running the following command:
`squeue -h -t R -O Partition,NumCPUs,tres-per-node` which is used to tell for a partition CPUs allocated for the job and the resources like GPU. However, the partition names that we have are long which causes the columnar output to be treated as one value.

Output:

```
gpu-2080ti-interacti8                   gpu:1               
gpu-2080ti-interacti8                   gpu:1               
gpu-2080ti-interacti8                   gpu:1               
gpu-2080ti-interacti8                   gpu:1               
gpu-2080ti-interacti8                   gpu:1               
gpu-2080ti-interacti8                   gpu:1               
gpu-2080ti-interacti8                   gpu:1               
gpu-2080ti-interacti8                   gpu:1
gpu-2080ti-long     32                  gpu:4               
gpu-2080ti-long     16                  gpu:2               
gpu-v100            4                   gpu:1
```

If I run a awk on the above command as `squeue -h -t R -O Partition,NumCPUs,tres-per-node| awk "{print \$1,\$2,\$3}"` will be problematic because `gpu-2080ti-interacti8` is treated like one value rather it should have been `gpu-2080ti-interacti    8`. I have already looked up for -o with --format but that does not work for me since `tres-per-node` does not exist in the % options that `squeue` provide. I am looking for a solution that can help me separate those values.

Comment: Can't you use the `NF` (Number of Fields) constant of `awk`?

Comment: Maybe you can use the minimum field with or suffix specification in `squeue`'s `-O, --Format=<output_format>` option argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-O, --Format` allows specifying a column width with `:`. So you can try

```
squeue -h -t R -O Partition:30,NumCPUs,tres-per-node
```

Replace the `30` with the maximum length of all partition names.

Comment: I was trying to do it this way squeue -h -t R -O --Format="%.10Partition,NumCPUs,tres-per-node" which did not work. But this works very good. Thank you.